# Could not build Objective-C module 'PryntTrimmerView'

Tags: swift, module, importerror

I am getting the following error:

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'PryntTrimmerView'
```

I am trying to insert [this](https://github.com/HHK1/PryntTrimmerView) project into my project. I installed the pods and now I am trying to import the module but I keep getting this error.